# Yocto Bitbake fails on ros-image-turtlebot3-core.bb:do_rootfs due to missing rpm

Tags: raspberry-pi3, yocto, rpm, bitbake, ros2

I like to assemble a Linux image for RaspberryPi with ROS2 and Turtlebot3 stuff. Yocto environment is already set up and worked fine until end of last year. Image file was successfully built and started as expected at target system.
My new application needs further dependencies, therefore I pulled latest changes from origin repositories few days ago. Unfortunately, this seem to broke functionality of build system. Own changes not yet applied.

**Build process fails at the last stage when rootfs should be created. It claims several rpm would be missing. It turned out they're existing at different location.**

Below example is about *glibc-localedata-pa-pk-2.31-r0.cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4.rpm* but after several tries I noticed that a tons of packages are affected.

**Expected**: build/BUILD-poky-foxy-dunfell/deploy/rpm/cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4/glibc-localedata-pa-pk-2.31-r0.cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4.rpm

**Existing**: build/BUILD-poky-foxy-dunfell/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/glibc-locale/2.31-r0/deploy-rpms/cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4/glibc-localedata-pa-pk-2.31-r0.cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4.rpm

Another afftected package:

**Expected**:
build/BUILD-poky-foxy-dunfell/deploy/rpm/cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4/libatomic1-9.3.0-r0.cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4.rpm

**Existing**: build/BUILD-poky-foxy-dunfell/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc-runtime/9.3.0-r0/deploy-rpms/cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4/libatomic1-9.3.0-r0.cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4.rpm

Basically rpm are expected to be at build/BUILD-poky-foxy-dunfell/**deploy/rpm**/cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4/ but they are at build/BUILD-poky-foxy-dunfell/**work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/XXX/YYY/deploy-rpms**/cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4/

Were there any changes in buildsystem or configuration since end of 2020 or any known issues found? Any help would be appreaciated, many thanks in advance!

```
$ bitbake ros-image-turtlebot3-core -k
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION           = "1.46.0"
BUILD_SYS            = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING      = "universal"
TARGET_SYS           = "arm-poky-linux-gnueabi"
MACHINE              = "raspberrypi3"
DISTRO               = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION       = "3.1.11"
TUNE_FEATURES        = "arm vfp cortexa7 neon vfpv4 thumb callconvention-hard"
TARGET_FPU           = "hard"
DISTRO_NAME          = "Poky (Yocto Project Reference Distro)"
ROS_DISTRO           = "foxy"
ROS_VERSION          = "2"
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION   = "3"
meta                 
meta-poky            
meta-yocto-bsp       = "dunfell:6a7335170ed70263c4b2c55d10fe741c237c2357"
meta-oe              
meta-python          
meta-perl            
meta-networking      = "dunfell:c56d6309efc11e9f0f4a549be45a783c73a49ba0"
meta-raspberrypi     = "dunfell:59c2d6f7a8b1239bd7b587b9180c2a55f9c695a2"
meta-ros-common      
meta-ros2            
meta-ros2-foxy       
meta-ros-backports-hardknott 
meta-ros-backports-gatesgarth = "ros2foxy:638a8b93e7b328fab9ccf2321bea039a93a57dde"
meta-communication   
meta-system          
meta-usercode        = "ros2foxy:886b2fed39384970dc7476a15009765785b52512"

Initialising tasks: 100% |##########################################################################################| Time: 0:00:16
Sstate summary: Wanted 367 Found 365 Missed 2 Current 2770 (99% match, 99% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
ERROR: ros-image-turtlebot3-core-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Error executing a python function in exec_python_func() autogenerated:

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:
File: 'exec_python_func() autogenerated', lineno: 2, function: <module>
     0001:
 *** 0002:do_rootfs(d)
     0003:
File: '/home/user/ros_target/poky/meta/classes/image.bbclass', lineno: 247, function: do_rootfs
     0243:    progress_reporter.next_stage()
     0244:
     0245:    # generate rootfs
     0246:    d.setVarFlag('REPRODUCIBLE_TIMESTAMP_ROOTFS', 'export', '1')
 *** 0247:    create_rootfs(d, progress_reporter=progress_reporter, logcatcher=logcatcher)
     0248:
     0249:    progress_reporter.finish()
     0250:}
     0251:do_rootfs[dirs] = "${TOPDIR}"
File: '/home/user/ros_target/poky/meta/lib/oe/rootfs.py', lineno: 975, function: create_rootfs
     0971:    env_bkp = os.environ.copy()
     0972:
     0973:    img_type = d.getVar('IMAGE_PKGTYPE')
     0974:    if img_type == "rpm":
 *** 0975:        RpmRootfs(d, manifest_dir, progress_reporter, logcatcher).create()
     0976:    elif img_type == "ipk":
     0977:        OpkgRootfs(d, manifest_dir, progress_reporter, logcatcher).create()
     0978:    elif img_type == "deb":
     0979:        DpkgRootfs(d, manifest_dir, progress_reporter, logcatcher).create()
File: '/home/user/ros_target/poky/meta/lib/oe/rootfs.py', lineno: 366, function: __init__
     0362:        self.manifest = RpmManifest(d, manifest_dir)
     0363:
     0364:        self.pm = RpmPM(d,
     0365:                        d.getVar('IMAGE_ROOTFS'),
 *** 0366:                        self.d.getVar('TARGET_VENDOR')
     0367:                        )
     0368:
     0369:        self.inc_rpm_image_gen = self.d.getVar('INC_RPM_IMAGE_GEN')
     0370:        if self.inc_rpm_image_gen != "1":
File: '/home/user/ros_target/poky/meta/lib/oe/package_manager.py', lineno: 765, function: __init__
     0761:            self.primary_arch = self.d.getVar('MACHINE_ARCH')
     0762:
     0763:        if needfeed:
     0764:            self.rpm_repo_dir = oe.path.join(self.d.getVar('WORKDIR'), rpm_repo_workdir)
 *** 0765:            create_packages_dir(self.d, oe.path.join(self.rpm_repo_dir, "rpm"), d.getVar("DEPLOY_DIR_RPM"), "package_write_rpm", filterbydependencies)
     0766:
     0767:        self.saved_packaging_data = self.d.expand('${T}/saved_packaging_data/%s' % self.task_name)
     0768:        if not os.path.exists(self.d.expand('${T}/saved_packaging_data')):
     0769:            bb.utils.mkdirhier(self.d.expand('${T}/saved_packaging_data'))
File: '/home/user/ros_target/poky/meta/lib/oe/package_manager.py', lineno: 733, function: create_packages_dir
     0729:                if destdir not in seendirs:
     0730:                    bb.utils.mkdirhier(destdir)
     0731:                    seendirs.add(destdir)
     0732:                try:
 *** 0733:                    os.link(l, dest)
     0734:                except OSError as err:
     0735:                    if err.errno == errno.EXDEV:
     0736:                        bb.utils.copyfile(l, dest)
     0737:                    else:
Exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/user/ros_target/build/BUILD-poky-foxy-dunfell/deploy/rpm/cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4/glibc-localedata-pa-pk-2.31-r0.cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4.rpm' -> '/home/user/ros_target/build/BUILD-poky-foxy-dunfell/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/ros-image-turtlebot3-core/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo/rpm/cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4/glibc-localedata-pa-pk-2.31-r0.cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4.rpm'

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/user/ros_target/build/BUILD-poky-foxy-dunfell/work/raspberrypi3-poky-linux-gnueabi/ros-image-turtlebot3-core/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.2708
ERROR: Task (/home/user/ros_target/3rdParty/meta-ros/meta-ros-common/recipes-core/images/ros-image-turtlebot3-core.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 9034 tasks of which 9033 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/user/ros_target/3rdParty/meta-ros/meta-ros-common/recipes-core/images/ros-image-turtlebot3-core.bb:do_rootfs
Summary: There were 358 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

**Edit:**
I tried to make all missing RPM available by symlinks. Since really a lot (but still not all) packages were affected, I created short script for that:

```
#!/bin/bash

currDir=`pwd`

#find all existing RPM in WORK directory
find build/BUILD-poky-foxy-dunfell/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi -iname "*.rpm" > ${currDir}/tmp_allRpm.log

#find all RPM that are already deployed
cd build/BUILD-poky-foxy-dunfell/deploy/rpm/cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4/
ls -1 *.rpm > ${currDir}/tmp_deployedRpm.log
cd $currDir

#create list of all RPM that are not yet deployed
grep -v -f ${currDir}/tmp_deployedRpm.log ${currDir}/tmp_allRpm.log > ${currDir}/tmp_toBeLinkedRpm.log

#create symlinks
xargs -i ln -s {} build/BUILD-poky-foxy-dunfell/deploy/rpm/cortexa7t2hf_neon_vfpv4/ <${currDir}/tmp_toBeLinkedRpm.log
```

This seemed to solved the origin issue but lead to further weired errors. So I decided to set up new Yocto/OpenEmbedded environment using my existing config files and recipes. It turned out to be a good decision - after several hours of compilation everything was done ;) Only downside of this is that I can't tell what went wrong and when it may happen again?!